# Using Stream to sum Object fields in List

Tags: java, list, arraylist, sum, java-stream

I'm trying to sum the fields of a List and return the value. I wanted to use a stream for this but I'm new to streams and am not sure if a stream can accomplish this or not. This is what I've tried but I think the syntax is incorrect.

```
    public double calculateCartTotal(ArrayList cartItems) {
        
        this.totalPrice = cartItems.stream()
                .map(item -> item.getTotalItemPrice())
                .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
        

        return totalPrice;
        
    }
```

Relevant class structure for context.

```
public class Cart {

private double totalPrice;
private List<CartItem> cartItems;

public Cart() {
        super();
        this.totalPrice = 0;
        this.cartItems = new ArrayList<CartItem>();
    }
   //other methods
}


public class CartItem {

    private Product productName;
    private int numberOfUnits;
    private double totalItemPrice;
    private double unitPrice;

    public CartItem(Product productName, int numberOfUnits) {
        super();
        this.productName = productName;
        this.numberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;
    }
    //other methods

}
```

Get total and unit price methods

```
public double getTotalItemPrice() {
        return this.getUnitPrice() * numberOfUnits;

    }

    public double getUnitPrice() {
        return Double.parseDouble(productName.getCurrentPrice());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems.

1. Missing type parameter of `ArrayList`. This is problematic, because now we don't know if the list actually contains `CartItem`s. Also you usually want to avoid using the implementation of collections for the declaration e.g. `List<CartItem> items = new ArrayList<>();` is much better.
2. Not converting the stream to a `DoubleStrem`. Using a `DoubleStream` has the advantage, that it doesn't convert your primitive double to a `Double` object. Additionally it's made to work with number unlike the normal `Stream` so it comes with useful methods like `sum` and we don't have to use `reduce`.

Example code

```
public double calculateCartTotal(List<CartItem> cartItems) {
    this.totalPrice = cartItems.stream()
        .mapToDouble(i -> i.getTotalItemPrice())
        .sum();
    return totalPrice;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the usage with the Stream and catching the type parameter. It's compiling now and is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `cartItems` parameter as a `List<CartItem>`:

```
public double calculateCartTotal(List<CartItem> cartItems) {

    this.totalPrice = cartItems.stream()
           .mapToDouble(CartItem::getTotalItemPrice)
           .sum();
    return totalPrice;

}
```